# Default location and window size when a new window is opened?

Tags: windows-10, display

So when I open up some app, it always appears in the centere of the display and with its default size, is there any place I can set the default the location and size for that program? also, is there a "minimize when opened" option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends entirely on the application. It is not a Windows (10) Setting.

Most Office apps will open where they were before.
Task Manager (and some like tools) have Open Minimized.
Other apps are misbehaved and open anywhere.

Nonetheless it is the app's responsibility where and how to open.

You would have to look at each app to determine what its options are available for how to open.

Answer (score 0):

For some apps, you can modified how they start by changing the parameter of their shortcuts properties. For example, in the case of VLC shown on the image below, changing the Run parameter will affect how it opens.

[image: IMG:]